# Collapse Booststrap Well When Link Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I've built a nav menu using expand and collapse in and not using a dropdown. My problem is that I can't get the div to toggle when I click a menu link. I've tried using js to toggle it closed when a link is clicked, but then I can't re-open the menu again.

Here's my html:

```
<header style="padding:0px 0%;">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="margin:0px 0px;">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavmenu" aria-expanded="true" style="color:#fff;display:inline-block;">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right inverse hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="margin:0px 0px; font-size:0.8em;">
          <li style="float:left !important"><a href="/" style="text-align: left; padding:8px 0px;"><img src="/products/greg2/images/avatierwatermark.png" style="height:34px; width:auto;"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>


<div class="collapse" id="expandmenu">
  <div class="well">
        <div class="container">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle2 pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#expandmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" style="float:right; padding:16px 5px 17px 0px; color:#333;"><p class="explore" style="font-size:0.8em; color:#333;">Close </p>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.1em;"></span>
</button>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12">

            </div>
                 </div>

    <div class="row">


        <ul class="expand txt-ctr" style="padding-left:0px;">
            <li class="blue"><a href="#passwordstationbenefits" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><div style="background-position:0px 0px;"></div><span>Benefits</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#overview" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><div style="background-position:-165px 0px;"></div><span>Overview</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#design"><div style="background-position:-330px 0px;"></div><span>Features</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#reporting"><div style="background-position:-495px 0px;"></div><span>Reports</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#security"><div style="background-position:-660px 0px;"></div><span>Security</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#helpdesk"><div style="background-position:-825px 0px;"></div><span>Help Desk</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#appsupport"><div style="background-position:-990px 0px;"></div><span>App Support</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#architecture"><div style="background-position:-1155px 0px;"></div><span>Architecture</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#languages"><div style="background-position:-1315px 0px;"></div><span>Languages</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#ticketing"><div style="background-position:-1490px 0px;"></div><span>Ticketing</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#textimonials"><div style="background-position:-1665px 0px;"></div><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="/products/identity-management/password-management/password-station/demo/"><div style="background-position:-1825px 0px;"></div><span>Demo</span></a></li>
             <li class="blue"><a href="#resources"><div style="background-position:-1998px 0px;"></div><span>Resources</span></a></li>
            <li class="blue"><a href="#payingtwice"><div style="background-position:-2165px 0px;"></div><span>True Cost</span></a></li>
                </ul>

</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the js I've tried:

```
$('.collapse a').click(function(){
  $("#expandmenu").toggle();
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would say the problem is in your JQuery. When you choose the class .collapse, you shouldn't get a as a child. Try doing it with separate selector

Comment: [This](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) might hep you. Use `.collapse('show')` to show and `.collapse('hide')` to hide instead of `toggle`.

Comment: I've tried using .blue, .collapse, and #expandmenu... all of them work to get the div to collapse, but then I when I hit the menu icon to open it again nothing happens. It seems like "toggle" is behaving like "hide". I think I might be missing a step that causes things to reset once the menu collapses.

Comment: Like this J Santosh? '$('.collapse a').click(function(){
  $('#expandmenu').collapse('hide');
});'

Comment: Can you specify which menu you're talking about? Is it the a links within "avatiernav" or within "expandmenu"? Also can you add your code to jsFiddle. I can't seem to get what you have on your post to work in jsFiddle.

Comment: @hieu-le here's a link to the project http://www.avatier.com/products/greg2/password.php

Comment: Looking at the console for developer tools, it says this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function.  It looks like you need this from bootstrap to get rid of the error. Do you have that? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: @hieu-le yeah I just changed it back to #expandmenu.... I was experimenting trying to get it to work. Still doesn't.

Comment: can you please give instructions on how to recreate your problem on your site? Tell me exactly where to click and stuff to recreate the problem with the menu not opening anymore.

Comment: @hieu-le click "Explore" on the top right. Then click any of the menu links. The menu should collapse after you click a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
$('#expandmenu a').click(function(){
  $("#expandmenu button").click();
});
```

Comment: that works great except for some reason, not on a smartphone. Any ideas?